# Adding New folder in treeview c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am using Treeview in C# winforms to list all existing images in directory, i also created button event to  add New Folder, but now problem is when i add new node its created but in actual no any folder created on actual drive/directory, so please help me out.
Here is my Code..

```
private void btnAddFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var newNode = treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add("New Folder");
newNode.BeginEdit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any code for creating directories there - just for adding the node to your tree.

I am assuming you have some kind of path information on each node (perhaps in the 'Tag' data). If that's the case, you need to combine this data with a call to CreateDirectory, as follows:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as string, "New Folder"));
```

This will create a directory which is represented by the combination of the path of the current node and the string 'New Folder'.

The TreeNode.Tag property is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The Directory.CreateDirectory method is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The Path.Combine method is described here [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: really works..Thank you, but what i want after creating new folder we can change name of folder, so what is the way to get that folders rename string??? after this
    newNode.BeginEdit(); After finishing editing

Comment: Don't create the folder until the node editing is complete! Then you can use the final value to create the folder.

Comment: Yes that what i want exactly but where we can add createDirectory code?? means is there any method/Event for Node editing  complete? Because on that even i want to check that folder is already exist or not..

Comment: Got the solution treeView1_AfterLabelEdit mehod...Thank you